# Breeze - Server Left Join Result into Breeze Entity Type

Tags: left-join, metadata, breeze

I am performing a left join on the server and returning a new object corresponding to that of an object defined in the metadata. However, breeze seem not to recognize the type of the returned object.

I have an entity, School whose metadata is loaded.  School looks something like

```
public class School{
  public int Id{ get; set;}
  public string name {get; set;} 
}
```

my query looks like

```
var r = EntityQuery.from('School')
```

In my method, if I `return ContextProvider.Context.Schools`, then the results are received as of type School.

However, if i `return ContextProvider.Context.Schools.select(s => new School{})`, the the results are not recognized to be of type School. The everything execures fine but I cannot just get the results as an object of type School.

Is there a defined way of doing left joins with breeze s so that newly created objects will be recognised?

Answer (score 0):

Providing that you have the [BreezeController] attribute annotating your ApiController then this should work.

If not, take a look at what is sent over the wire, the *json.net* serializer should have added a '$type' property to each json entity returned. The default breeze *jsonResultsAdapter* uses this property to determine the 'EntityType' needed to create a breeze entity corresponding to each of the json entities.

If you don't see the '$type' property then the *json.net* serializer has not been configured property.  If you do the '$type' property then check you local client side metadata to see if this type has been defined. If not then you need to either manually create it or have it sent from the server.